# How to generate Beatty's sequences that contain all natural numbers lower that $N$ using $r$ and $s$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Beatty sequence says that every irrational number can generate two sequences of acending numbers where every positive integer belongs to exactly one of these sequences.
$$\mathcal{B}_r = \left( \lfloor{nr}\rfloor\right) \qquad n \geq 1\\
\mathcal{B}_s = \left( \lfloor{nt}\rfloor\right) \qquad n \geq 1\\
\mathcal{B}_r \cap \mathcal{B}_s = \varnothing\\
\mathcal{B}_r \cup \mathcal{B}_s = \mathbb{N}\\
Where\qquad s = \dfrac {r}{r - 1}$$

Therefore for every natural number $N$ and irrational number $r$ we can generate two sets of integers that contain all nubers $\{i \in \mathbb{N}: 1 \leq i \leq N\}$:
$$\mathcal{B}_r = \left( \lfloor{nr}\rfloor\right) \qquad 1 \leq n \leq m\\
\mathcal{B}_s = \left( \lfloor{ns}\rfloor\right) \qquad 1 \leq n \leq j\\
\mathcal{B}_r \cup \mathcal{B}_s = \left(n\right)\qquad 1 \leq n \leq N$$

For example:
$$ N = 10, \qquad r = \sqrt{2} \quad\Rightarrow\quad s = 2 + \sqrt{2}\\
\mathcal{B}_r = \left(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9\right) \qquad m = 7\\
\mathcal{B}_s = \left(3,6,10\right) \qquad\qquad\quad j = 3$$

Now what I want to do is calculate the values of $m$ and $j$ for each given natural number $N$

$$\lfloor{mr}\rfloor \le N\\
\lfloor{mr}\rfloor \lt N + 1\\
mr \lt N + 1\\
m \lt \frac{N+1}{r}\\
m = \lfloor{\frac{N+1}{r}}\rfloor\qquad(1)$$

Similaryly we find that:

$$j = \lfloor{\frac{N+1}{s}}\rfloor\qquad(2)$$

However when I try to implement $(1)$ and $(2)$ to compute $m$ and $j$ values I don't get the expected values when $N$ gets large. I'm not sure if the problem is with my coputer program or the above equations, Are $(1)$ and $(2)$ correct for $\{N \in \mathbb{N}: 1 \le N \le 10^{100}\}$?

#### Error example:

```
>>> N
2102607186491202768324985186154486949972248746737044231178178291724599849547926451438364791930880L
>>> n
1486767799739497169195432937353753354226423926286278051482159206775440977387852125373193825288192L
>>> j
615839386751705599129552248800733595745824820450766179696019084949158872160074326065170966642688L
>>> n == ((N + 1) / sqrt(2))
True
>>> j == ((N + 1) / (2 + sqrt(2)))
True
>>> floor ((sqrt (2)) * n) <= N
True
>>> floor ((2 + sqrt (2)) * j) <= N
False
>>>
```